# In android to which thread's message queue a handler is bound?

Tags: android, handlers

I know a handler is bound to the thread's message queue in which it is created, but what if i create a handler in a service and posting a runnable declared in activity to which my service is bound.
For example:
In service:-

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
handler.post(Mainactivity.runnable);

In activity inside oncreate method:-

Runnable runnable=new Runnable(){
    public void run{
       //some code here
    }
};
```

Can someone please explain me what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Please find information about Message Queue and `Looper` in below link

[Understanding Android Core: Looper, Handler, and HandlerThread](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-core-looper-handler-and-handlerthread-bd54d69fe91a#.48qwyyaha)

In the Android via `Looper`, `Handler`, and `HandlerThread`. The System can be visualized to be a vehicle as in the article’s cover.

1.`MessageQueue` is a queue that has tasks called messages which should be processed.

2.`Handler` enqueues task in the `MessageQueue` using `Looper` and also executes them when the task comes out of the `MessageQueue`.

3.`Looper` is a worker that keeps a thread alive, loops through `MessageQueue` and sends messages to the corresponding handler to process.

4 Finally Thread gets terminated by calling `Looper’s` quit() method.

Answer (score 0):

By default service will run on `UI Thread`. So the handler you create on service will post the runnable on `UI Thread`

Comment: I used IntentService which runs on serparate thread so why it is posting in main thread

Comment: And my runnable object is static in my Activity that's why i can call it by activity's name

Comment: though you use `IntentService`, `onCreate()` will be called on main thread.